# Character Array not copying using strcpy

Tags: c, arduino

I'm checking a text file (using an HTTP request) for a number. I want to keep track of this number each time it changes, so I'm gathering the HTTP response in a character array and comparing it to the previously stored count (tried an int, and now trying a character array) but it doesn't seem to be storing the result. `lastCount` is a global variable, and this function is what's used to check and store the new count:

```
boolean checkCount()
{
  char currentLine[15];
  int index=0;
  if (client.connected())
  {
    Serial.println("Connected. Checking for availabilty of client...");
    if (client.available())
    {
      Serial.println("Client is available! Trying to read from client...");
      // read incoming bytes:

      if(client.find("\r\n\r\n"))
      {

      char inChar;
      while(inChar=client.read())
      {
        if(inChar==-1) break;
          currentLine[index] = inChar; //read in all characters of count
          currentLine[index+1] = '\0';
          index++;
        Serial.print("\n\nCurrent count count: ");
        Serial.print(currentLine);
        Serial.print("\n\n");
      }
      if(strcmp(currentLine,lastCount)!=0) //not equal
      {
        Serial.println("NOT EQUAL TO LAST COUNT");
        Serial.print("last count: "); //test output
        Serial.print(lastCount);
        Serial.print("current count: ");
        Serial.println(currentLine);

        strcpy(lastCount, currentLine);//, sizeof(lastCount));

        Serial.println("BLINKING LED");
        blink(3);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("EQUAL TO LAST COUNT");
        Serial.println("NOT BLINKING.");
      }

      delay(5000); //delay 5 seconds (don't kill server)
      return true;
     }
     else
     {
       Serial.println("newlines not found - error with request");
       return false;
     }
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("count not available");
      return false;
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: You've sprinkled in several print statements... why not print the value of lastCount in a few places (function entry, after the strcpy).

Comment: @Marian he tagged it c, and it looks like c (with some non-standard c keywords; #defines I assume). The `Serial.println` you're probably curious about -- I assume `Serial` is a structure, and its `println` element is a function pointer, and the same for `client.*`. The tip-off that it couldn't be Java is the calls to `strcpy()` and `strcmp()` as functions without any object qualification.

Comment: `Serial` is an Arduino-specific thing.
When I print the lastCount value, it's always empty. It's as if my strcpy isn't doing anything. Am I calling it wrong? Been away from C for awhile, excluding this project.

Comment: @rar your code is doing a strcpy correctly but perhaps a straight strcpy is not appropriate to meet your needs. This is why I gave a (too) subtle suggestion that you print the value of lastCount, particularly before the if comparising it, and after the strcpy call. It would be good to print currentLine in both of these places too.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I printed lastCount in several places and it would always be empty, as if it wasn't being stored properly. I realized that there was an error in another function I was calling that may have caused problems and ended up fixing both functions by following Jerry_Y's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following code:

You should put this '\0' at the end of the string in the array.

currentLine[index+1] = '\0';  this line should be called out of the "while loop".
Otherwise strcmp alway got only one character from the "currentLine".

**And please take care of the array length of the string buffer when you store the input**

```
while(inChar=client.read())
{         
    currentLine[index++] = inChar; //read in all characters of count
}
currentLine[index] = '\0';

if(strcmp(currentLine,lastCount)!=0) //no
```

Comment: What do you mean by "take care of the array length of the string buffer when you store the input". Do you mean when I use `strcpy` to store the last count? Or just when I'm reading the characters?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem. I still get lastCount as empty when I output it.

Comment: I mean when you read the char string and put it in "currentLine", the string length should be considered. I don't know what your input looks like, I think there is **potential** buffer overflow issue if the input string is very long.

Comment: And do you mind show us the content of the "currentLine" after client.read() finished?

Comment: I'm expecting a simple number from the file. Here's what I'm currently getting from inside the loop: `Current follower count: 2
äS` Note that this is before the terminating character is added, so once it's added and I output it again, I just get `2`, rather than the extra characters.

Comment: I guess you get into your while loop for only once. You can also print the value of "index" to take a look. I think you should check client.read() to make sure it works well.

Comment: Your original suggestion ended up fixing my problem. I had to fix another function I was using to follow the same method (not sure why I was managing my input in that strange way). I'm still running out of memory on my Arduino, but that's a problem for another day!